# mysql update table with values from another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my table 'supplier_stats' with the values from my other table 'supplier_change_request'.

My two tables look like the following:

Supplier_change_request

```
id   |   user_id   |   company_name   |   supplier_number
1        123           hewden             V0001
```

Supplier_stats

```
Id | user_id | company_name  |  address  |   reference   | supplier_number
1    123       pie              n/a          12345         V0001
2    145       gates            n/a          12345         V0002
```

Here is my MySQL:

$reference = '12345'

```
$query = "UPDATE supplier_stats 
SET supplier_stats.company_name = (
    SELECT supplier_change_request.company_name 
    FROM supplier_change_request
    WHERE supplier_change_request.reference = '$reference' AND supplier_change_request.supplier_number = supplier_stats.supplier_number";
mysql_select_db('hewden1');
$retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn )
```

by my calculation this should be setting the value of company_name where supplier_number is 'V0001' in my table 'supplier_stats' to 'hewden'. However the company_name is not being updated.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: I can not see any column supplier_change_request.reference in your table

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is a bit off in your query and that it should look like this (just the SQL, adapt to PHP as needed):

```
UPDATE supplier_stats ss
JOIN supplier_change_request scr ON scr.supplier_number = ss.supplier_number
SET ss.company_name = scr.company_name 
WHERE ss.reference = '$reference'
```

The column `reference` pointed to the `supplier_change_request` in your sample query, but to `supplier_stats` in your sample data - I assumed the sample data was correct; change if not.

This query should change the `company_name` in `supplier_stats` from `pie` to `hewden`.